# Query SQL Server table with RowVersion

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am querying SQL Server from VBA using ADODB. All of my tables have RowVersion (timestamp/varbinary) columns. Since VBA doesn't support the varbinary type, I convert the RowVersion to a string from a SQL Server function. A simple query will look like:

```
sql = "SELECT NameValueListID, dbo.RowVersionToString(RowVersion) AS RowVersion FROM NameValueLists WHERE NameValueListID=1
```

To get the data onto a sheet, I first tried range.CopyFromRecordset. This worked until I included the above function in the sql call. Adding the RowVersionToString function caused the recordset to return what seems like a random set of data - less rows than excepted and fewer column than I asked for. Never could figure that one out. I then used rs.GetRows which returned the expected data and I could use range.value = rsData successfully. Below is a sample call that works.

```
Private Sub Test_Scratch()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sqlCmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim sqlConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sql As String
    Dim rsData() As Variant

    Set sqlConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    sqlConnection.Open ModSQL.GetConnectionStringByStage(wsSetup.Range("suAppStage"))

    sql = "SELECT NameValueListID, dbo.RowVersionToString(RowVersion) AS RowVersion FROM NameValueLists WHERE NameValueListID=1"
    Set sqlCmd.ActiveConnection = sqlConnection
    sqlCmd.CommandText = sql
    Set rs = sqlCmd.Execute

    rs.MoveFirst

    rsData = rs.GetRows
End Sub
```

I then added a second varbinary column to the query (it's not a RowVersion but is of the same type). So the sql will look like:

```
sql = "SELECT NameValueListID, dbo.RowVersionToString(RowVersion) AS RowVersion,  dbo.RowVersionToString(LastItemRowVersion) AS LastItemRowVersion FROM NameValueLists WHERE NameValueListID=1
```

After the call, the recordset rs has all the data, but rsData has "Empty" for the first varbinary column. The order doesn't matter. Only the last varbinary column has a value, the other is always "Empty" in the rsData array.

Comment: Why do you need the timestamp value in your query anyway? Curious what you are trying to use it for.

Comment: @SeanLange Because that is a very easy way to implement optimistic concurrency. An app will read the row with that value. At a later point when it wants to update the row in some fashion, it includes the original value in the where clause. If the update affects no rows, then the app knows that it was changed after retrieval.

Comment: I can use rowversion to get only changed rows. So I download some records, then I can get max Rowversion and then get new / updated records that have rowversion > maxRowVersion

Comment: rsData is an array. How do you specifically import rsData into an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: I used SELECT NameValueListID,cast(RowVersion as bigint), cast(LastItemRowVersion as bigint) and rsData(0, 0), rsData(1, 0), rsData(2, 0) all had values

Answer (score 0):

I guess,more could anser your question if you showed your code of user function RowVersionToString.What is the definition of argument of RowVersionToString?It might be that the argument "RowVersion" was interpreted to a data type not but a colmun name.

```
sql = "SELECT NameValueListID, dbo.RowVersionToString(NameValueLists.RowVersion) AS RowVersion,  dbo.RowVersionToString(LastItemRowVersion) AS LastItemRowVersion FROM NameValueLists WHERE NameValueListID=1
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30091422)